# Books/Notes on Synchronization in Dynamical Systems + Networks?

Tags: reference-request, nonlinear-system, network

I am interested in references on Synchronization in Dynamical Systems, if possible from a Network perspective. Unfortunately I am an outsider to the field of Dynamical Systems and am not sure how to look for or whether my starting points into this area are the best ones. 
I am working with the following material:

"Synchronization: A Universal Concept in Nonlinear Sciences" by Pikorsky et al. Nicely written but lacking the textbook aspect I could use for self-study.

"Dynamic Processes on Complex Networks" by Barrat et al also has a chapter or so on this but it is too short- and the style of writing is not very rigorous or detailed.

"Synchronization on Complex Networks", a Physics Reports survey by Arenas et al covers a wider ground on the specific topic I am looking for but, being a survey, is limited on what it can achieve for self study.

My feeling is also that this an intense area of work right now and that many of these references do not reflect with the frontier.

My question would be whether there is any other book or set of lecture notes that goes rigorously and with detail over the necessary material? This does not seem easy has it would have to combine a lot of ground on Nonlinear Dynamics + Networks results (say, on graph spectra), but I thought I would ask. Perhaps a combination of two different textbooks, each going deep in the respective area, would achieve a better result? Any suggestions on how to attack this would be greatly appreciated!

Best
v

Comment: Did you end up finding any material? You can answer your own question if you did. I would find it helpful.